# Does modern type theory include specifications and implementations?

Tags: types

Good programming practice distinguishes between specification (at the API level) and implementation. I would have thought that this same distinction would be found in type theory.  Perhaps I just don't understand what I'm reading, but I don't see it.

Apologies if I'm completely off (and corrections appreciated), but it seems that in type theory one adds new computation rules (generally reduction rules), which in effect are at the implementation level, i.e., they compute something. I don't see how one adds anything like a specification.

Thanks for your help in clarifying this.

Comment: Maybe it's better to ask your question in cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks. I've done that. No answers so far.

Comment: A nice answer in cs.stackexchange: http://goo.gl/S4CPQD